# (Done) Can we look at reopening the Hardware to Software question

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I had a go at editing this, mostly just removing unnecessary noise.

[From Hardware to Software](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122055/from-hardware-to-software)

It seems on topic to me, there are a few valid strategies, one of which I outlined as did another answer by Fattie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you voters, appreciate the assist.